# How to install ClusterSSH (cssh) on CentOS?

Tags: linux, centos, package-management

How can I install ClusterSSH on CentOS?

I can find some old guides online, but they seem outdated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `clusterssh` package can be found in [EPEL](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL). You can install it as follows

`yum -y install epel-release && yum -y install clusterssh`

Comment: Maybe a more precious way on how to do it would be great.